# Why can't I use an installed Zoom add-on for "Outlook on the web" in Brave Browser?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, zoom-meeting

My work requires me to use Outlook, so I am using "Outlook on the web", which is like a worse gmail. Similar to gmail, it allows the user to install add-ons, one of which is Zoom's, so I can add unique Zoom meetings to my Outlook calendar events.

When using the Zoom tool in Chrome and Safari, I am taken to a permissions "allow" flow that authorizes Zoom and then I can add meetings. However, in Brave, I am never taken to that flow, I just get the error `Zoom is working on your Add a Zoom Meeting request.` and the flow never starts. Even with Brave "Shields DOWN" the flow never starts.

How do I enable the Zoom add-in in Brave?

Comment: Maybe try a "standard" Browser (Edge, Chrome) and see if that works.

Comment: @John it does work, it's mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. In order to authenticate with Zoom, I turned the Brave Shield off. Once I was authenticated and able to add a zoom link to my calendar invite in Outlook, I was able to turn the Brave Shield back on and everything still worked as expected.

It seems as though you may need to turn your Brave Shield off, log into the Zoom Add-On and then you should be good to go and fine to turn the Brave Shield back on.